# How to set torify + whois work correctly?

Tags: command-line, manjaro, tor, whois

i'm using manjaro. I'm trying to use: `torify whois`, `torsocks whois`, `proxychais whois`. I tried to do that with `sudo` command, and all this command give me back the same output:

```
[Feb 23 21:15:57] PERROR torsocks[3181]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:185)
getaddrinfo(whois.verisign-grs.com): Non-recoverable failure in name resolution
[manjaro@manjaro Desktop]$
```

I asked friend to do the same operation on his distro, and for him it work perfectly :( could someone help me with that ?

Answer (score 5):

Start `tor` first:

```
$ tor
blah blah blah
... [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
```

Then open another terminal and use `torify` / `torsocks` with whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

run this command

```
systemctl start tor
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step you wanna do is start the tor service.

```
/etc/init.d/tor start
```

or

```
service tor start
```

The next thing you wanna do is start `tor` on your command line. I am on kali-rolling and `tor` command just works for me.

After doing that, the next thing you should do is

```
torify curl ifconfig.me
```